# No Module Named Pydirectinput

Tags: python, pip, pynput

I have a problem and ı cant find anythink to help. I am getting the error shown in the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it installed?

```
python -m pip install pynput
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32061674)

Comment: @Hafnernuss It can be a potential solution, maybe this is all what they need.